# Building Windows Azure SDK for .NET

Tags: azure

I have an issue with building Windows Azure SDK for .NET (https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net). I cloned repository `git clone https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net` and then checkout dev branch `git checkout dev`. When I am trying to build it, I get such errors `Unable to find version '1.0.5105.25348-prerelease' of package 'Hydra.Generator'. ComputeManagement` for different projects. In file "azure-sdk-for-net\src\ComputeManagement\readme.txt" sates that somehow I should setup Hydra.Generator package. Unfortunately I have no idea about this package and how to setup it. I have tried to find something in google, but did not manage.

What should I do for building this SDK?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you building the SDK versus just using the binaries?

Comment: First of all it is interesting for me. Second, I wanted to make some changes for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble, we've made some recent changes to our build environment.

If you remove the Hydra packages from the NuGet packages.config file (you might need to comment out some of the Hydra goo at the bottom of the .csproj files as well), you should be OK for now.

We're working on a better fix - sorry. Do let me know how this goes for now. If/when we fix this properly I'll follow up here as well.

> Hydra btw is an unofficial code generation technology we use, but at this point it requires a separate NuGet feed in order to use, as this work is not ready for any public consumption at this point. You should be able to build successfully once you get past this NuGet not found issue.

Comment: Hydra looks like a very cool technology to generate model and services, are there any plans to make it available for public? maybe limited availability?

Comment: Eventually the hope is to share it so everyone can help build out these REST libraries. I don't have the timeline as I work on a different team these days; I figure the name will change in time, etc.

Comment: FYI, this technology is now called "AutoRest" and is up on GitHub here: github.com/Azure/autorest